# Getting values of two column as comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I need to get the results of the query in two separate columns because I am doing of two separate queries

```
 Select STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(Task.ID as varchar(100))
                from dbo.TaskRepeted 
                join dbo.Task on Task.id = TaskRepeted.Taskid
            where TaskID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') as Tasks 
    
    UNION ALL 
    
     Select STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(CoreTask.ID as varchar(100))
                from dbo.TaskRepeted 
                join dbo.CoreTask on CoreTask.id = TaskRepeted.Taskid
            where TaskID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') as CoreTasks
```

it is display only one column as: Tasks

and two rows:

1st row has the data: `3344,3,43,6,7,6,7,,34,3,443,434`
second row is null

but my data should appear like this:

```
Tasks                               CoreTasks
3344,3,43,6,7,6,7,,34,3,443,434     0 (if null is coming, it should display me 0 else it will display the comma separated values)
```

Comment: I'm just baffled.  The query returns two *rows*, each with one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two columns, don't use `union`:

```
 Select STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(Task.ID as varchar(100))
                from dbo.TaskRepeted join
                     dbo.Task on Task.id = TaskRepeted.Taskid
            where TaskID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') as Tasks ,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(CoreTask.ID as varchar(100))
                from dbo.TaskRepeted join
                     dbo.CoreTask on CoreTask.id = TaskRepeted.Taskid
            where TaskID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') as CoreTasks
```

Comment: ok, what about if first query or second return me null, i want them as 0

Comment: but where to add the coalesce, ?, because when not null, it should return me comma seperated values, else 0

Comment: ```Select isnull(STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(Task.ID as varchar(100))
                from dbo.TaskRepeted join
                     dbo.Task on Task.id = TaskRepeted.Taskid
            where TaskID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,''),0) as Tasks ,
        isnull(STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(CoreTask.ID as varchar(100))
                from dbo.TaskRepeted join
                     dbo.CoreTask on CoreTask.id = TaskRepeted.Taskid
            where TaskID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,''),0) as CoreTasks ```